# Does iphone 3g supports Calibri font?

Tags: iphone, ios, uifont

Hello I am using Calibri as UILabel setFont, but it is not working in 3g giving error,,,

is it available in 3g or not, because in 4g it is working perfect .....

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that there is any support for Microsoft ClearType fonts in iOS.  For other Apple products support is only included with Microsoft Office products.